# CAGradientLayer cannot change color

Tags: ios, calayer

I want a colored gradient to overlay my view. In a view controller, I have this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
  gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, nil];
  gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1.0f);
  self.view.layer.mask = gradientLayer;
}
```

But even though the first color is red, I only ever see a black gradient. How can I display a red gradient instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Instead of setting the gradient as the layer mask, add the gradient layer as a sublayer of `view.layer`.

Layers use the layer mask mask to determine the alpha of their own content by using the alpha of the mask at each pixel, since your `gradientLayer` is fully opaque, the effect you were getting wasn't the one you were hoping for.

Layers are similar to views (views are actually wrappers for layers), you can add them as sublayers in a similar way that views are added as subviews.

Comment: An explanation of what setting a mask does could be nice, so that OP knows why it turned black :)

Comment: I expanded the answer as suggested by @Losiowaty